FTP Server defaulting to C: as directory
Forgive me if this is a silly question but recently I have been playing with configuring an FTP server for some testing and it has started dropping users into the C: drive rather than the Z: drive I defined as the path.
I set up a partition to act as my root directory, go to IIS and add an FTP site, during configuration I define my partition (Z:) as the physical path,I set my binding IP and port (standard 21), no host name and no SSL.I do some testing and it seems to be working fine, I load in through Filezilla and land in my Z: as defined during set up, great. Then, since I need SFTP as well, I install the needed SSH components and here's where it starts getting odd. After connecting through SFTP, I notice it's no longer dropping me into the Z: but rather the C: drive now. At this point I have changed none of the settings, all I have done is install the components for SSH.
Tried setting up a new FTP server and now the behavior is the same there as well, I am dropped into the C: drive rather than the Z:. Unsure of what to do I restart the system entirely but no change. I completely removed IIS and reinstalled out of morbid curiosity, went through the same process as before and still it drops me into the C: drive rather than the defined path as it originally had been.
I am unsure of what the issue is, I have checked the Physical path multiple times and it still is set at Z:, yet I can only ever land in the C: drive. To make matters worse, I can no longer connect to the server FTP any longer, only SFTP. Any advice on this would be appreciated.

This does not appear to be business or professional at all and thus is probably offtopic, but: SFTP is a different protocol from FTP and does not use the FTP server in IIS; it uses sftp-server.exe which is part of OpenSSH (what you call 'the SSH components') and uses the directory set by sshd which is the 'home' directory (on Windows the 'profile' directory) for the userid connected to -- typically C:\Users\%userid% (not just C:). Why your FTP-not-SFTP server now doesn't work you don't provide nearly enough info to even guess, but as I said it's probably offtopic.
